# how to get a good upload loader to work?

Tags: php, jquery, upload

i was looking at http://www.2shared.com and when you upload something it shows how fast the file is being uploaded, and other info. does anyone know how i can do this under php/jquery ?
ive used alot of loaders outthere and they dont work. most of them are under flash which i dont want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these:

- [FileChucker](http://encodable.com/filechucker/)
- [PHP upload progress](http://devpro.it/upload_progress/)

**jQuery:**

- [jqUploader](http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/test.php)
- [jQuery Ajax uploader plugin (with progress bar!)](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/)